# How to push a variable from a .gs function into an html file?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following code that automatically grabs the last **link** of a certain column of a the spreadsheet. I need to create a web app with a button that every time it's clicked runs the script and automatically opens in a new window the last link in the column. I need it to be in the form a of web app cause I need to embed the url into a button of an external site.

The .gs code extracting the last link in the column it's the following:

```
function obtainurl(){  
  var summarySheet = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Summary'); 
  var lastRow = "AA" + summarySheet.getLastRow(); 
  var new_url = summarySheet.getRange(lastRow).getValues();
  var new_url1=   [].concat.apply([], new_url)  
  return new_url1;
}
```

The code above works and returns me the correct link I have checked with logger.log. Then I have a combination of another .gs function:

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openUrl').setHeight(50);
}
```

And the correspondent html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <base target="_blank">
    <script>

      //Here is where i have the problem I don't know how to pass the url into the var above and get the correct link opened everytime.
      
      var winRef = window.open(new_url);
      winRef ? google.script.host.close() : window.alert('Allow popup to redirect you to '+url1) ;
      window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('url').href = url1;}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    If the download has not started please disable your ad-blocker! Or else contact us at -----
  </body>
</html>
```

In summary I don't know how to pass the url varible to the html file. I have check and if I hardcode the full url into the html file it works. However, this needs to be dynamic, always opening the last url in the spreadsheet column.

Thank you in advance, I know I am quite a newbie.

Comment: The web app has to request the data with a google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().ServerSideFunctionName() and then you can return data to SuccessHandler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your .gs function from the client with google.script.run and specify the function to execute once the server returns a value.

```
// Calls server function obtainurl()
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showUrl).obtainurl();

// Function executed after server returns value
function showUrl(url) {
  alert(url);
}
```

More details here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run